# Any Free Mouse Gesture App in WIndows 10 or 11?

Tags: windows, user-interface, mouse

When I search for "mouse gestures app" in windows, there are many "touchpad gestures" results. It's pretty weird, because touchpad gestures is completely different from mouse gestures. Are there any free mouse gestures app in windows 10 or 11?

For "Mouse gestures", I mean something like holding right click or middle click and then draw a graph to trigger commands/events.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could quickly find three.
Disclamer: I have never actually used any of them.

StrokesPlus - Open Source

[StrokeIt](https://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/) - Free for individual and not-for-profit

[gMote](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=1495) - Official website seems to be down

There are many other dedicated apps that do offer builtin mouse gestures, like web browsers and file managers. These tend to be better integrated and work much more reliably and provide better features.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am using www.strokesplus.net right now. It works very well. StrokesPlus .com link that you posted shows strokesplus.net is its replacement. You may add this to your answer too.